# MS Excel dynamic print area

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to create a dynamic Print_Area in Excel 2010 which will consist of two cell ranges.

For example the first cell range is `A1:J50` and the second range is `A100:J150`. These should print out on two pages, ignoring the cells that come in between these two ranges.

The four cells shown in the above example ranges should be dynamic, and not hard coded as simple Print_Area ranges. Therefore in my worksheet I used cells `AA1`, `AB1`, `AC1` and `AD1` to store values `"A1"`, `"J50"`, `"A100"` and `"J150"` respectively.

(The cells AA1, AB1, AC1 and AD1 actually use formulas to determine what cell address will be used, but for this question lets just assume the values are set as above).

I then used the Name Manager and entered the following formula under Print_Area:

```
=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AA$1):INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AB$1);INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AC$1):INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AD$1)
```

The result of this formula is exactly what I need, and it actually works the first time I print the ranges. However once I did that, Excel automatically substitutes the formula with the actual cell range that was calculated. So when I check the Print_Area in the Name Manager after printing once, it contains something like:

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:$J$50,Sheet1!$A$100:$J$150
```

Is there a way to prevent the Print_Area from converting my formula to calculated values, and instead using the formula every time I print? I would like to not use macros if at all possible (if not, I'll try macros too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and it seemed to work.

Create a new name called Test and set its value to (Note that I used a comma rather than the semicolon you had.  I have US language set)

```
=INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AA$1):INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AA$2),INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AA$3):INDIRECT(Sheet1!$AA$4)
```

Set your Print_Area name to

```
=TEST
```

Good luck!

***EDIT***

The above works for me, but it appears unnecessary.  I just tried to replicate the problem, and was unable.  When I have the Print_Area set to the formula with INDIRECT it does not replace after printing.

See this linked file.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgm0iv19u6igdm5/Book1.xlsx

Comment: Have you tried to print a second time too? I actually did try exactly what you suggested myself, but with the same result. It only worked one time, and then the formula (in this case the name TEST) gets replaced with the actual range that was calculated.

Comment: Yes  did.  I've printed, changed the cell values, saw visually that the range changed, printed again and it captured the new range.  "TEST" still has the INDIRECT formula.  (Running Excel 2010, all patched up)

Comment: Thanks, TEST does have the INDIRECT formula on my end too, but does your Print_Area have TEST set after the second time? I would guess that since you saw the range visually change the answer will be yes, which would indicate there's something wrong with my Excel 2010 installation (although I tried this with Excel 2007, and got the same issue).

Comment: Thanks for sending the file. I played a little bit with the ranges entering different cell values, and I got some mixed results. I'll try to figure this one out and come back with my findings. Although it still smells to me like some sort of installation issue.

Comment: Well, the worksheet I downloaded worked flawlessly with different ranges I entered, leaving me somewhat stumped. The only difference I could find (between your sheet and mine) was that the  content to be printed was on sheet and the cells used in the formula on another (in my case everything was on one sheet). So I guess for now I'll just use the cells on another worksheet for my Print_Area formula. I'm hard up for time so unfortunately can't experiment further with recreating the issue. Thanks again Ken, you're a life saver!